# How to set the sharing mode on a file when using open()

Tags: c, windows, winapi

When you open a file with [`CreateFile`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa363858%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) you can set its sharing mode (the third parameter).

Is there a way to set the sharing mode when using [`_open`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z0kc8e3z%28v=VS.71%29.aspx)? Possibly by a call to `_setmode` or something equivalent? I need to use the `FILE_SHARE_DELETE` mode.

Comment: There is another function that takes a share mode parameter.  I'm not at my computer at the moment, but it's either sopen, sfopen, or fsopen.

Comment: Thanks for the comment @Luke, `sopen` does permit setting read and write share modes, but not the delete mode which I have to use apparently.

Comment: If you pass the _O_TEMPORARY flag then the file is opened with FILE_SHARE_DELETE; however, it is also opened with FILE_FLAG_DELETE_ON_CLOSE so it will be deleted when you close the handle.  This might be acceptable depending on your needs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[_fsopen](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8f30b0db%28v=vs.80%29.aspx), [_sopen](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w7sa2b22%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) and similar functions can take a share mode parameter however this does not support `FILE_SHARE_DELETE`. If you want this share mode use `CreateFile`